# Validation error database in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I need help with validation error in database.

I have a model :

```
 function total ($id_student, $id_course){
         $query = $this->db->query('select total from student where id_student='.$id_student. ' and $id_course='.$id_course);
        if ($query->num_rows() <= 0) {
            return false;

        }
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $row = $query->row();
            return $row->total;
        }
     }
```

I have this code in the controller:

```
$id_course=array;
 $total = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($list_courses); $i++) {            
            $total[$i] = $this->student_model->total($id_student, $id_course[$i]);
            $error[$i]= $this->db->_error_message();
          if(!empty($error[$i])){
                    $total[$i] = 0;                    
                }
        }
```

The parameters $id_student and $id_course can  exist in the database or no.  I need that if the query gives error or the query not exists, skip the error, do $total[$i]=0 and don't show the error database and continue the loop.  I don't know how can I do this.  I have tried many options in the forums, but I couldn't.  Thanks for your help.  I'm sorry my english.

Comment: There are (I hope) some typos in your code; select total from student where id_student='.$id_student. ' and id_course='.$id_course and $id_course = array();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model method, you're returning false if the query doesn't produce a result. So you can do this:

```
$id_course=array;
$total = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($list_courses); $i++) {   

    // if query returns false, then $total[$i] will be false         
    $total[$i] = $this->student_model->total($id_student, $id_course[$i]);
    $error[$i]= $this->db->_error_message();

    // check if $total[$i] is empty/false, if so make it 0
    if(empty($total[$i])){
        $total[$i] = 0;                    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change the model function to;

```
public function total ($id_student, $id_course){
    $sql = "SELECT `total` FROM `student` WHERE `id_student` = ? AND `id_course` = ? LIMIT 1";
    // to prevent any sql injection, use binding
    $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($id_student, $id_course);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $row = $query->row(0);
        return $row->total;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Then change the controller to;

```
$id_course = array();
$total = array();
// why not use a foreach loop?
for ($i = 0; $i < count($list_courses); $i++) {
    $result = $this->student_model->total($id_student, $id_course[$i]);
    if ($result == 0) {
        $error[$i]= $this->db->_error_message();
    }
    $total[$i] = $result;
}
```

By return 0 from the model instead of FALSE it can go straight into the controller function.